# Not able to load workbook using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Here is the code that i am using to load workbook:

`import openpyxl
from sys import argv
genreUri = argv[1]
genre = openpyxl.load_workbook(genreUri)`

Above code throw this error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chaudhary/projects/genre/backend/utils/openpyxl/cell.py", line 26, in <module>
    genre = openpyxl.load_workbook(genreUri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 251, in load_workbook
    ws_parser.parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py", line 130, in parse
    dispatcher[tag_name](element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py", line 304, in parse_sheet_protection
    self.ws.protection = SheetProtection.from_tree(element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 100, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'undefined'
```

Comment: And what is arv[1] supposed to contain? A path to the workbook? Type into the terminal `argv[1]` and see if it returns anything... Post in the comments what  `argv[1]` returns

Comment: It contains the xlsx file path i.e '/home/demo.xlsx'.
 here it the sample file that is throwing this error https://expirebox.com/download/884826afdc27a8a391f253a0d5dc7fe7.html

Comment: Are you sure the xlsx file is actually available in the root of the .exe?